# Access bindingsource column value

Tags: c#, bindingsource

How can I update a column value in a binding source with code?

I am trying for something similar to this:

```
CustomersBindingSource.AddNew();
CustomersBindingSource.Current["CustomerID"] = Guid.NewGuid();
```

This code currently errors stating: "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'".

Any help re-writing this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

BindingSource's [Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.current.aspx) property is very generic in what it returns: type object. Object doesn't define an indexer so your [] doesn't work. What you need to do is cast the Current property to the (more-specific) type of what it really is.

For example, if Current is really a DataRowView, you could write:

```
DataRowView current = (DataRowView)CustomersBindingSource.Current;
current["CustomerID"] = Guid.NewGuid();
```

Hope this helps,
Ben