# Display String in a Database as a Checkbox

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a Windows Form that was mainly made using the graphical editor. It is connected to a database called, `Database1`. One of the tables in the database is called `Table1`, and contains the column `CheckBox1`. When I connected the form to the database, `Database1DataSet.xsd` and `Database1DataSet.Designer.cs` were automatically created.

`CheckBox1` can either hold "Yes" or blank (this wasn't my decision). I would like to make a checkbox checked if the value in the `CheckBox1` column is "Yes", and unchecked if the value is blank. If I drag a bound checkbox onto the form, it doesn't work because I assume that the values in the column need to be either 1 or 0. So I'm trying to work around this.

In my form, I have the following

```
// Form Constructor
public myForm()
{
    // Initializes all the components in the form
    InitializeComponent();

    // Change the checkboxes checked state
    this.myCheckBox.Checked = myCheckBox_Update();
}

// Method for determining if the checkbox should be checked
private bool myCheckBox_Update()
{
    // This SHOULD bring in the current record of the database
    DataRowView current = (DataRowView)this.Table1BindingSource.Current;

    try 
    {
        // This SHOULD determine if the value in the CheckBox1 field has a value
        return current.Row["CheckBox1"].ToString().Length > 0;
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("NullReferenceException was thrown!", "Error");

        return false;
    }
}
```

In the `InitializeComponent()` function, there is the following

```
// This line is generated when I drag a bound checkbox to the form
// this.myCheckBox.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("CheckState", this.Table1BindingSource, "CheckBox1", true));

// For the miscellaneous information about the checkbox
this.myCheckBox.AutoSize = true;
this.myCheckBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
this.myCheckBox.Name = "myCheckBox";
this.myCheckBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(92, 23);
this.myCheckBox.TabIndex = 0;
this.myCheckBox.Text = "Check Box";
this.myCheckBox.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
```

However, it keeps throwing a `NullReferenceException`. I'm assuming that this is because `this.Table1BindingSource.Current` cannot be cast as a `DataRowView`.

I have looked at several other posts on SO that are somewhat related to this problem (e.g. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169730/access-bindingsource-column-value), or [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147588/c-sharp-getting-values-from-datatable-or-bindingsource)), but I haven't found anything that has worked so far. The second link's answer doesn't work because I am iterating through the records with `this.Table1BindingSource.MoveNext();`, and I won't know the index.

Can someone steer me in the right direction? I'd really appreciate it

---

EDIT: The BindingSource is initialized with this

```
private System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource Table1BindingSource;
this.Table1BindingSource = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);
```

Comment: Is "return return" really not giving any errors on compilation in your try statement?

Comment: Are you sure that the field is blank or Yes? Could it be NULL or Yes?

Comment: Are you sure you want to cast it to a DataRowView and not a DataRow? Is your data source a DataGridView?

Comment: @eshs I casted to DataRowView because that is what the first link I posted did. I don't know what methods to use if I cast to DataRow. I don't think it is a DataGrid. I used the "New Data Source" wizard to connect to my database, and I am dragging controls from it to my form

Comment: Can you edit in the code that initializes the DataSource, probably in InitializeComponent()? You may be getting the NullReferenceException because you're casting Current to the wrong type.

Comment: @Steve The values in the field are either "Yes" or blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is just changing the values in my database from "Yes" and blank to 1 and 0. Then in the InitializeComponent() method, I added the following line (or it might be generated for you if you drag it from the data source panel)

```
this.myCheckBox.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("CheckState", this.Table1BindingSource, "CheckBox1", true));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll put this in an answer since it's not fit for a comment.

You may also try checking the value for null in your try statement.

```
try 
{
    // This SHOULD determine if the value in the CheckBox1 field has a value
    object val = current.Row["CheckBox1"];
    if (val == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    { 
        return current.Row["CheckBox1"].ToString().Length > 0;
    }
}
```

Or at least set a breakpoint at the if (val == null) statement and make sure val has a value that you would expect.

If by 'blank' you mean a String.Empty, then your code would work as you expect it to, but if blank means null, then you'll have to check for null, you can't call ToString() on a null value.

Comment: Blank as in `String.Empty`. When I put a breakpoint in, current and val are both null

Comment: @maj0rtom Set a breakpoint "DataRowView current = (DataRowView)this.Table1BindingSource.Current;" and make sure that Current has a value, and see what Table1BindSource.Current's type is in the Locals panel of VS.

Comment: `current` has a value of `null` (As does `this.Table1BindingSource.Current`). `Table1BindingSource.Current` has a type of `object`

Comment: Does Database1 get initialized, or is it null too? What is the full type name of Database1?

Comment: Do you mean `database1DataSet`? It is type `Database1DataSet` (both generated by VS), and there are no records when I try to view them from the Locals panel. I don't understand why though since `myCheckBox_Update` is after `InitializeComponent();`

Comment: Yes, it appears that the database is not being properly initialized, causing the null reference error. So the real problem is that your database is not loading into database1DataSet. Can you edit in the every reference to database1DataSet in InitializeComponent()?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52533/discussion-between-maj0rtom-and-eshs)